# How to see summary of feature changes since last pull?

Tags: git, github

I'm just using git for the first time as an occasional committer on a project I'm only involved in at a high level.

I pulled master for the first time this week and am finding that I really wish there was a way to see a summary of how the app has changed since I last worked on it.  Can I look up a list of branches that have been merged since commit `xxxxx`?  Or maybe there's a better way to git (heh) caught up?

(I *really* struggle with 'noise' so `git log` is difficult for me, at least without having it filtered somehow.)

Comment: We commit changes to release.md that gives a feature summary with each release. Doesn't help you now, but could in the future.

Answer (score 1):

### Use `--merges` Flag

Assuming you have real merge commits in your target branch (see caveats), then you can ask *git-log* just for those. For example:

```
git log --merges
```

Furthermore, you can ask it just for the merges since your last known date or commit. For example:

```
git log --merges <committish>..HEAD
git log --merges --since=<date>
```

### Caveats

The `--merges` flag will only show you merge commits. Cherry picking, shared patch series, rebasing, and other types of merge-like behavior aren't really "merges", and may not show up in your filtered log search. In such cases, a visual tree from *gitk* or by using `git log --graph` may be helpful.

You may also want to see if the `--branches` or `--all` flag can be helpful. Merges on other branches won't be displayed by default, and complex multi-branch merge history may be omitted or obscured if you only look at the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

Last pull moved your `origin/master` branch. To see commits since the last pull run

```
git log origin/master..master
```

You can get a nice summary with `git shortlog`:

```
git log origin/master..master | git shortlog
```

To see a graph of branches run

```
git log --graph --decorate --all origin/master..master
```

Comment: `git pull` will normally update local `master` (assuming you have `master` checked out, and there are no conflicts), so if you have ran `git pull` recently, `git log origin/master..master` will print nothing. If you ran `git fetch`  these commands could be used to print the delta commits between local master and what was recently fetched from remote.